# Automatically pressing a button with javascript through Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

There is a button on a site that I need to click automatically when I view the page, and it is the below button:

```
<a class="btn" data-building="main" id="main_buildlink_main" href="#">Submit</a>
```

However, when I use the following code in a greasemonkey script, it is not working:

```
var submiting = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
submiting.initEvent("click", true, true);
document.getElementById('main_buildlink_main').dispatchEvent(submiting);
```

What part of the code did I do wrong?

---

Update:

This was marked as a duplicate, so I tried the answer on the linked page and it still does not work. This is now my code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Upgrade
// @namespace   Upgadevillage
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @include     *
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

function upgrade (jNode) {
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}

//-- Value match is case-sensitive
waitForKeyElements (
    //"#btn_submit a[id='main_buildlink_main']",
    "a[id='main_buildlink_main']",
    upgrade
);
```

Comment: Did you try just `click()` on the element?

Comment: Yes I did, also no luck.

Comment: Which doesn't make since, because if I type the click() event in the address bar, it works.